# Javascript "priveleged" methods that are not re-created per object?

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

When looking around for emulating private methods from other languages, commonly Crockford's page is suggested that proposes this "priveleged" method:

```
function Container(param) {

    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;

    this.service = function () {
        return dec() ? that.member : null;
    };
}
```

So `service` is priveleged - it can access private methods (like `dec`) and private variables (like `secret`). I assume it can also call "public" methods (those assigned to `Container.prototype`).

However, isn't `service` re-created for every object of `new Container`? Doesn't it take extra time and consume extra memory? And the private `dec` too, for that matter.

I understood that the recommended JS way to make methods is on `KlassFunction.prototype` to avoid this performance problem. But can non-public methods be created this way at all?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Setting it on the `prototype` would allow all instances to reference one function, instead of recreating it each instantiation. But like you've noticed, that method would not be able to reference any "private" variables in the constructor. That's usually a tradeoff

Comment: There's no reason to expect that the *code* for the private functions is re-created each time the constructor is called. The runtime (probably) creates a new Function instance, but a modern implementation will be able to share the code. I don't think that memory use should be much of a concern unless you're creating millions of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really two kinds of private.

1. The kind of private rigorously enforced in runtime. This always has a runtime penalty of course. Here `private` is used as a security mechanism. Completely useless in Javascript.
2. The private to signal your interface to other developers that is not obviously enforced at runtime. You can still
   access fields if you want using reflection. Here `private` is used to prevent accidental misuse of class internals.

If I guess correctly, you are trying to achieve the second goal by doing the first. The second goal can be achieved
simply by conventions and enforcing those conventions in your build step. There is no need to take that into the runtime.

The memory use (pressure put on GC actually) is not the only problem, the closure class pattern is incredibly inflexible in that you cannot reuse, share or inherit
the functions in any way. And you cannot access the variables outside even for temporary reasons. Also read http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/01/19/the-cost-of-privacy/